# Error when using Serializable in Android

Tags: java, android, serialization

I am trying to parse an object in Androud using Serializable, but i keep getting an IOExeption

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.cille_000.laesomondo, PID: 5290
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.logic.TestLogic)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1526)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1474)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:723)
                  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
                  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:763)
                  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8655)
                  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3052)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
                  at com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.logic.TestLogic.showTextInfo(TestLogic.java:47)
                  at com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.startscreen.TestInfoFragment.onClick(TestInfoFragment.java:44)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.startscreen.CreateUserActivity
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
                  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1521)
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1474) 
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:723) 
                  at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408) 
                  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133) 
                  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:763) 
                  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8655) 
                  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3052) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1518) 
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75) 
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856) 
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507) 
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475) 
                  at com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.logic.TestLogic.showTextInfo(TestLogic.java:47) 
                  at com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.startscreen.TestInfoFragment.onClick(TestInfoFragment.java:44) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I can see that the problem is with the CreateUserActivity, but i do not get why. 
The class im using Serializable on is:

```
package com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.logic;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.challengescreen.QuizActivity;
import com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.challengescreen.ShowTextActivity;
import com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.challengescreen.TestResultActivity;
import com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.entities.ReadingTest;
import com.example.cille_000.laesomondo.entities.User;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestLogic implements Serializable{
private ReadingTest readingTest;
private Long startTime, stopTime, startPause, stopPause;
private ArrayList<Long> pauses = new ArrayList<>();
private Long totalTime;
private int standardReadingSpeed = 3;
private int correct = 0;
private transient Context context;
private User user;
private int textID;
private QuizActivity quizActivity;


public TestLogic(Context context, User user){
    this.context = context;
    this.user = user;
    readingTest = new ReadingTest(context);
    quizActivity = new QuizActivity();
}

public void showTextInfo(int textID){
    this.textID = textID;
    setText(textID);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowTextActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("logic", this);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.putExtra("Writer",getWriter());
    intent.putExtra("Resume", getInfo());
    intent.putExtra("Title", getName());
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public void beginTest(int id){
    setText(id);
    ShowTextActivity showText = new ShowTextActivity();
    showText.setText(getText());
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, showText.getClass());
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("logic", this);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void getResult(){
    int xp = calculateXP();
    String result = "Antal korrekte svar: " + correct + "\n" +
            "Du læste teksten på " + totalTime/1000%60 + "sekunder" + "\n" +
            "Du får " + xp + " xp";
    user.addXp(xp);
    TestResultActivity testResultActivity = new TestResultActivity();
    testResultActivity.setInfo(result);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, testResultActivity.getClass());
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("logic", this);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public void setText(int id){
    readingTest.setTextID(id);
}

private String getText(){
    return readingTest.getText();
}

private String getName (){ return readingTest.getName(); }

private String getWriter (){ return readingTest.getWriter(); }

private String getInfo (){ return readingTest.getInfo(); }

public void getQuestion1() {
    quizActivity.firstQuestion(readingTest.getQuestion1());
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, quizActivity.getClass());
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("logic", this);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public void getQuestion2() {
    quizActivity.secondQuestion(readingTest.getQuestion2());
}

public void getQuestion3() {
    quizActivity.thirdQuestion(readingTest.getQuestion3());
}


public void beginPause(){
    startPause = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void stopPause(){
    stopPause = System.currentTimeMillis();
    pauses.add(stopPause-startPause);
}

public void stopTimer(){
    stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    totalTime = stopTime-startTime;
    for (int i = 0; i< pauses.size(); i++){
        totalTime = totalTime- pauses.get(i);
    }
}

private int calculateXP(){
    long seconds = totalTime/1000%60;
    int readingspeed = readingTest.getWordCount()/standardReadingSpeed;
    int xp = (readingTest.getLix()*correct)+readingspeed-(int) seconds+50;
    if(xp <= 10){return 10;}
    else {return xp;}
}

public void checkAnswer(int question, int answer){
    int correctAnswer = readingTest.getCorrectAnswer(question);
    if(answer == correctAnswer){
        correct++;
    }

}

public int getTextID(){
    return textID;
}
}
```

And there is no reference between TestLogic and CreateUserActivity.

How can i get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that one or more members of the TestLogic class (ReadingTest, User, QuizActivity) or one of those classes' members are not Serializable.

All of your objects, across the entire object graph, must be serializable for this to work.

Also, be aware that while putting Serializable objects into a Parcel is possible, it's not recommended. Whenever you are creating your own classes for use in an Android app, you should implement Parcelable instead of Serializable

Comment: P.S. - TestLogic has a member of type Context.
I could be mistaken, but I don't think that Context is Parcelable or Serializable, and it's not something that I think you could reasonably store and reconstitute. Oh, and by it's name, I'm guessing that QuizActivity is an Activity. That won't work either, for the same reason as Context (an Activity is a Context).

Comment: I have used transient on Context, but the error I am getting is in the CreateUserActivity and not in the TestLogic